# calculating "levenshtein social network" *very* efficiently

Tags: levenshtein-distance, performance

I'm doing a code challenge online involving finding the 'social network' of words who are related through their Levenshtein distances.  My Levenshtein function is correct.  I'm recursively adding to a global set, and I'm using a map of tuples to boolean values to cache whether or not any pair of words has a Levenshtein distance of 1.  The code is supposed to terminate in *5 seconds.*  I'm not sure how this is even close to possible.  I'm sure that there is some *aha* insight that makes 
this possible.  Can anyone see that right off the bat?

**Problem Statement:**
Two words are friends if they have a Levenshtein distance of 1. That is, you can add, remove, or substitute exactly one letter in word X to create word Y. A word’s social network consists of all of its friends, plus all of their friends, and all of their friends’ friends, and so on. Write a program to tell us how big the social network for the word 'hello' is, using this word list

**My pseudocode:**

```
get_network(friend)
  if friend not in network
    add friend to network
    friends = []
    check friend against all words in network
      consult cache or calculate lev distance
      cache if necessary, append to friends if necessary
    for all friends
      get_network(friend)
```

**To rephrase the question:** "what's the fundamental insight that makes possible an astronomical boost in efficiency?"

Comment: You seem to have surprisingly little trust in this community..

Comment: Can you replicate the problem statement somehow? Not everyone here has an account on that website.

Comment: Please do not post links that require registration to view.

Comment: sorry, didn't realize it was behind a login, I will edit